# Reading JSON data, without a parent root name?

Tags: c#, json

Can someone advise how I to read the following JSON data?

```
[
  {
    "ref": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "year": 2016
  },
  {
    "ref": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "year": 2016
  }
]
```

I have tried reading with JObject.parse, but would appear to fail because there's no  name to the parent?

I have no control on the format of the data being read, as it comes from a 3rd party source.

Comment: That's a `JArray`.

Comment: You can simply deserialize this as a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Entity
{
    [JsonProperty("ref")]
    public int @ref { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(jsonString);
```

`ref` is a reserved keyword in c# so you need to use JsonProperty attribute to bind to a property with a different name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DeserializeObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) method available in JSON.NET to return a collection of [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) objects :

```
var json = @"[{""ref"": 1, ""name"": ""name1"",""year"": 2016},{""ref"": 2,""name"": ""name"",""year"": 2016}]";

// Build a list to store your objects
var references = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>(json);

foreach(dynamic reference in references)
{
    // Each dynamic object in here can be referenced as expected
    // (e.g. reference.name, reference.year and reference["ref"]
    Console.WriteLine("ref: {0}, name: {1}, year: {2}",reference["ref"], reference.name, reference.year);   
}
```

An [example of this can be seen here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oQsNzW) and example output can be seen below ;

```
ref: 1, name: name1, year: 2016
ref: 2, name: name, year: 2016
```

If you already had a class to represent the associated type, then you could bind directly to it when you serialized via :

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClassName[]>(json);
```